Severe Overexposure When Taking Photos in Auto Mode (Nikon coolpixa)
When I use the camera in auto mode to record videos, everything works perfectly fine. However, when I switch to taking single photos in the same mode, the images become severely overexposed (click for larger version):




Is it possible you have exposure compensation set for stills by accident?

The colours look "off" in this photo. I don't think it is overexposed, there is just some effect being applied to the image I think. Take a look at the camera manual, specifically the section on "Image Enhancement".

I think the exposure compensation is right. And I upload the new picture to address well. :)

The last photo shows that the "correct" exposure is 1/2000 F20 ISO100, but for some reason the exposure you're getting from auto uses a slower shutter speed (1/1250) and a wider aperture (F6.3). Could it be that it uses a metering mode you're not expecting?

Wait, are you actually in auto mode, or are you in aperture prioty mode? The A in the second photo seems to suggest that it's aperture priority (see page 52 of the manual).

Those comments can make an answer.  ;o)

To start off: your camera seems to be capable of exposing correctly as the last photo in Manual M mode shows with settings 1/2000 F20 ISO100. So nothing seems wrong with your camera.
I think the confusion starts with the used mode. You state:

When I use the camera in auto mode

The second photo shows an A, which seems to suggest you're using aperture priority mode, not auto mode (manual, p. 54). In that mode you select an aperture, and the camera calculates a fitting shutter speed and ISO value.
So you've set it to F6.3 and the camera calculated the shutter speed of 1/1250. I suspect your ISO is fixed at 100 as well, but it could also be set to "auto" allowing the camera to decide.
If you want the camera to decide the exposure fully you could try the programmed auto P mode (page 53 of the manual).
On why this seemed to work fine while recording the movie: Page 39 of the manual indicates that the exposure can only be set before the recording. Perhaps you've set the aperture, metered something bright (e.g. the sky), the camera decided on the shutter speed and then you pressed record. The camera kept the higher shutter speed, allowing for a better exposure.
